# Como adaptar esse sistema de login em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, login

Preciso de criar um sistema simples interno de login para aplicar num blog. Eu não consigo fazer meu código funcionar de jeito nenhum, e preciso de ajuda.

Esse é o Código:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
 function Login(){
  var done=0;
  var usuario=document.login-inputs.usuario.value;
  usuario=usuario.toLowerCase();
  var senha=document.login-inputs.senha.value;
  seha=senha.toLowerCase();
  if (usuario=="admin" && senha=="admin") {
   window.location="/p/admin.html"; done=1;
  }
  if (done==0) { alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente"); }
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<div id="all">
 <div id="login-box">
  <div id="login-header">
   Faça login no sistema
  </div>
  <div id="login-inputs">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Nome de usuário" name=usuario>
   <br />
   <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name=senha>
  </div>
  <div id="enviar">
   <input type="button" onclick="Login()" class="botao" value=Login>
   <a href="#">Esqueceu a sua senha?</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Alguém arruma o Script por favor? (não posso modificar o HTML)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiro um **alerta**: evite autenticar através de JavaScript, pois é extremamente inseguro, um exemplo, basta alguém visualizar o código fonte da página pra ver o usuário e senha, além de outros problemas. Como alertou o bfavaretto é quase como não ter nenhuma autenticação.

Bom, você diz que não pode alterar o HTML, mas há alguns erros nele, como a falta de aspas no valor do atributo `name` dos *inputs*. Também alterei a forma como captura os valores dos *inputs* no *script*.
Recomendo que defina um ID nos *inputs*, pois ao pegar pelo nome, se houver mais com o mesmo nome, pode haver problemas.

```js
function Login() {
  var done=0;
  var usuario = document.getElementsByName('usuario')[0].value;
  usuario=usuario.toLowerCase();
  var senha= document.getElementsByName('senha')[0].value;
  seha=senha.toLowerCase();
  if (usuario=="admin" && senha=="admin") {
    window.location="/p/admin.html";
    done=1;
  }
  if (done==0) { alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente"); }
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <div id="login-box">
    <div id="login-header">
      Faça login no sistema
    </div>
    <div id="login-inputs">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome de usuário" name="usuario">
      <br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
    </div>
    <div id="enviar">
      <input type="button" onclick="Login()" class="botao" value="Login">
      <a href="#">Esqueceu a sua senha?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Caso realmente faça por Javascript, é bom você ofuscar o script depois de pronto, mas se lembre de manter uma cópia legível

Comment: Sim, no caso esse sistema de login seria para uso interno mesmo, num blog de conteúdo escolar. Minha ideia   era linkar o JS e encriptar o src só pra não deixar exposto mesmo.

Comment: @DanielBonifácio, nunca duvide da astucia do Usuário, eles são capazes de coisas incríveis para quebrar ou bular um sistema. acredite, sempre tem um curioso para fuçar o JS.

Comment: @TobyMosque, eu compreendo. Acontece que realmente não há ninguém que tenha esse conhecimento que irá acessar ao blog, e fora que não haverá necessidade de pegar a senha de X ou Y usuário, visto que somente são redirecionados à uma página com suas notas e avisos pendentes / trabalhos pendentes.

Comment: @DanielBonifácio, talvez uma saída viável, seja criar um dominio para a sua escola (caso não exista), associar ele ao google apps e autenticar usando o Google Oauth.

Comment: @TobyMosque, não conhecia essa ferramenta. Interessante e eficiente. Obrigado pela dica :D

Answer (score -3):

```
function Login() {
  var done=0;
  var usuario = document.getElementsByName('usuario')[0].value;
  usuario=usuario.toLowerCase();
  var senha= document.getElementsByName('senha')[0].value;
  seha=senha.toLowerCase();
  if (usuario=="admin" && senha=="admin") {
    window.location="/p/admin.html";
    done=1;
  }
  if (done==0) { alert("Dados incorretos, tente novamente"); }
}
<div id="all">
  <div id="login-box">
    <div id="login-header">
      Faça login no sistema
    </div>
    <div id="login-inputs">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome de usuário" name="usuario">
      <br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
    </div>
    <div id="enviar">
      <input type="button" onclick="Login()" class="botao" value="Login">
      <a href="#">Esqueceu a sua senha?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```